# SQL-Query doesn't find rows even there are enough

Tags: c#, sql, mysql-connector

I'm writing a little webcrawler for my own site. It seems to work fine. I browse threw every link and check if it belongs to my homepage. If a link was found, it adds the Site with "addSite()". This first tries to get entries where the URl is the same and if there aren't any entries it adds the URl. Otherwise it updates it if the content hash changed. The problem is that it adds the URl even if it exists.

This is my method:

```
private bool addSite(string url, string title, string content)
{
    string hash = md5Hash(content);
    List<object[]> res = sql.executeReader(string.Format("SELECT `hash` FROM `sites` WHERE `url` = '{0}'", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url)));
    if (res.Count > 0)
    {
        if (res[0][0].ToString() != hash)
        {
            sql.executeQuery(string.Format("UPDATE `sites` SET title = '{0}', content = '{1}', hash = '{2}' WHERE url = '{3}'", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(title), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(content), hash, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url)));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    sql.executeQuery(string.Format("INSERT INTO `sites`(url, title, hash, content) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(title), hash, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(content)));
    Console.WriteLine("Added: " + url);
    return true;
}
```

I hope anyone can find the failure. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you checked the sql statement generated by your C# code ? what is it ? did you try to execute it in the your database manager ?

Comment: if on sql server. you can use sql profiler to view the exact query generated.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a mistake in database design. The url hadn't enough space and was cut.

Answer (score 2):

if there is a fiedl you dont want repeated. why dont you set the database field to be unique. and catch the error on your program or do as you want when exists. if the db allow it to go in. then the string is different by capital letter or space, etc.

Comment: Because I have to check if the content has changed. I can do it all in one query but first I want to get it working. A small query is easier to debug as a big query ;).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you have to add else:

```
    private bool addSite(string url, string title, string content)
    {
        string hash = md5Hash(content);
        List<object[]> res = sql.executeReader(string.Format("SELECT `hash` FROM `sites` WHERE `url` = '{0}'", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url)));
        if (res.Count > 0)
        {
            if (res[0][0].ToString() != hash)
            {
                sql.executeQuery(string.Format("UPDATE `sites` SET title = '{0}', content = '{1}', hash = '{2}' WHERE url = '{3}'", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(title), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(content), hash, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url)));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            sql.executeQuery(string.Format("INSERT INTO `sites`(url, title, hash, content) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(url), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(title), hash, MySqlHelper.EscapeString(content)));
            Console.WriteLine("Added: " + url);    
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No. Because at the IF-Block there is always a return. :(

Comment: Vielen Dank für eure Hilfe. Es war ein dummer Fehler. Und zwar habe ich der URl nicht genug Platz gegeben und sie wurde abgeschnitten.